# selinux blocking vsftpd directory listing

Tags: centos, selinux, vsftpd

I am trying to get a better understanding of selinux and configuring a local ftp repository on Centos7.

I installed `vsftpd` on my host.

I created a repository on my host:

```
/var/ftp/pub/centos7
  EFI
  EULA
  GPL
  images
  isolinux
  LiveOS
  Packages
  repodata
  RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
  RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Testing-7
  TRANS.TBL
```

When I try to list my available repository I get an error on my guest vm:

```
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
ftp://X.X.X.X/pub/centos7/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno] FTP Error 550 - Server denied you to change to the given directory
Trying other mirror/
ftp://X.X.X.X/pub/centos7/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno] FTP Error 550 - Server denied you to change to the given directory
Trying other mirror/

repo id     repo name            status
local-repo  Centos7 Repository   0
repolist: 0
```

However if I `setenforce 0` or `setsebool ftpd_full_access 1` my repository works.

```
repo id     repo name            status
local-repo  Centos7 Repository   3,723
repolist: 3,723
```

Obviously leaving `setenforce` to `0` is not advised but is leaving `setsebool ftpd_full_access` set to `1` the correct way to configure a local ftp repository? What am asking is, is there a correct way to configure an ftp repository with selinux running?

If anyone can point me in the right direction it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've configured `vsftpd` on CentOS 7 in the past, and from what I can tell the Boolean `ftpd_full_access 1` is OK, also you have the `# setsebool -P ftp_home_dir 1` option if you need it. This link might be helpful: http://www.tuxfixer.com/vsftpd-installation-on-centos-7-with-selinux/

Comment: What is the output of `ls -Zd /var/ftp/pub/centos7/`?  Perhaps the labels are wrong?  Or one of the parent directories?  Does running `restorecon -rv /var/ftp` fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after messing up my ftp directory's labels, and had to manually set SELinux types to allow FTP users to see files:

```
sudo chcon -Rt public_content_t /var/ftp/
```

Comment: The best method would be to set the permissions in the selinux configuration and do a `restorecon` on that folder so as not to loose the correct settings later upon a global re-labeling.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. [ftp://192.168.122.1/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] FTP Error 550 - Server denied you to change to the given directory]

Initially thought its a permission or some sort of security issue but its not.

When i tried to download repomd.xml file from client machine using wget [wget ftp://192.168.122.1/repodata/repomd.xml] it said file not found.

In my case issue was, in configuration file /etc/vsftp.conf my repodata directory was are supposed to be /var/ftp (**anon_root=/var/ftp/pub**) but i had kept under /var/ftp/. It expects "repodata/repomd.xml" to be placed under "/var/ftp" according to the settings in vsftp.conf

Then I just moved my sub directories inside /var/ftp::

```
root@uday-linux:/var/ftp# pwd
/var/ftp
root@uday-linux:/var/ftp# ls
openstack-queens-rdo-repo
root@uday-linux:/var/ftp# ls openstack-queens-rdo-repo/
openstack-queens  rdo-qemu-ev  repodata  rhel-7-server-extras-rpms  rhel-7-server-optional-rpms  rhel-7-server-rh-common-rpms  rhel-7-server-rpms
root@uday-linux:/var/ftp# ls
openstack-queens-rdo-repo
root@uday-linux:/var/ftp# mv openstack-queens-rdo-repo/* .
root@uday-linux:/var/ftp# rmdir openstack-queens-rdo-repo
root@uday-linux:/var/ftp# ls
openstack-queens  rdo-qemu-ev  repodata  rhel-7-server-extras-rpms  rhel-7-server-optional-rpms  rhel-7-server-rh-common-rpms  rhel-7-server-rpms
root@uday-linux:/var/ftp# 
root@uday-linux:/var/ftp#
```